# How to get a xml attribute variable (type double) using xPath in response using Wiremock

Tags: wiremock

Request is an xml like this:

```
<Request>
  <Account>373953192351004</Account>
  <Amount>98.21</Amount>
</Request>
```

Response is a json and should have amount mapped from request but data type being a decimal number (not String) e.g.

```
{
  "response": {
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "amount": 98.21
  }
}
```

i was able to do it with xPath using json mapping like this:

```
"amount": "{{xPath request.body '/Request/Amount/text()'}}"
```

but above xpath makes amount  a string with double quotes in the response, like:

```
  "amount": "98.21"
```

How do i make it without quotes like:

```
  "amount": 98.21
```

note: I can't remove the quotes in "{{xPath... as it wouldn't be a valid json anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the double quotes from outside the `{{ xPath ... }}`. So:

```
"amount": {{xPath request.body '/Request/Amount/text()'}}
```

Comment: As I already mentioned in note, quotes can't be removed as it makes it an invalid json. Application doesn't start and throws this error: ```Exception in thread "main" com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.MappingFileException: Error loading file /Users/111/workspace/mock-server/src/test/resources/mappings/11111.json:
Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{
```

Comment: I think we're missing some context here. Can you post the full JSON for your stub?

Comment: `{
  "method":"POST",
  "url":"/test-url",
  "request":{
    "bodyPatterns":[
      {
        "matchesXPath":{
          "equalToXml":"<Account>373953192351004</Account>",
          "expression":"/Request/Account"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "response":{
    "jsonBody":{
      "response":{
  "status":"SUCCESS",
        "amount":"{{xPath request.body '/Request/Amount/text()'}}"
      }
    },
    "status":200
  }
}`

Comment: I suggest you switch to using `body` rather than `jsonBody`, which takes a string rather than a JSON object. That way it doesn't have to be valid JSON and you can remove the quotes.